# How to split the screen dynamically in android without xml

Tags: android, xml

I have tried to split the screen using xml..here is the code
Please try this xml..I need the same layout programatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="318dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple">

        <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="318dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@android:color/holo_purple">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="318dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="318dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
        </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

But, I need to do programatically to split the screen. Can anyone provide me the solution?

Comment: Is there a particular part of the xml that you are having trouble recreating in code?  Are you able to provide any code you have done so far?

Comment: @user2145222:see this pic..http://www.mediafire.com/view/myfiles/#m6l4q71av9x43h7     I did in xml...but now i need it in programatically in activity

Comment: sorry but that doesn't answer my questions.  I am not confused about what you are trying to do, I simply wish to know where you are stuck.  Presumably you have at least got as far as some code to create some linearlayouts?

Answer (score 0):

By splitting the screen you mean dividing layouts width then you can try as below..

```
// gets the screen width
            float screenWidth = getWindowManager()
                    .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
```

You will get screen width from above code..

and for screen height

```
// gets the screen height
        float screenHeight = getWindowManager()
                .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

then all you have to do is set the layout width using LayoutParams.

```
LinearLayout view  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ur_layout_id);
view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) screenWidth / 3,
                    (int) screenHeight , 1f));
```

you can set layoutwidth to divide screen in half by `screenWidth / 2`, in 3 parts by `screenWidth / 3` and so on..
Hope this helps..

Comment: Assuming this solves the problem, wouldn't it be easier to use the weight property rather than using window manager? For example: setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1)) used within a horizontal linearlayout parent would split the screen width equally.  Dinesh even uses this in the second linearlayout in the xml provided (just vertically)  Perhaps I have missed something?